# python get module variable by name

Tags: python, variables, module

I'm trying to find a way to access module variable by name, but haven't found anything yet. The thing I'm using now is:

```
var = eval('myModule.%s' % (variableName))
```

but it's fuzzy and breaks IDE error checking (i.e. in eclipse/pydev import myModule is marked as unused, while it's needed for above line). Is there any better way to do it? Possibly a module built-in function I don't know?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary if you providean example code I'll accept this answer. There's really no such example I could find in the web.

Comment: **Do not ever use `eval` for data that could ever possibly come from outside the program. It is a security hole that enables the author of the data to run arbitrary Python code on your computer. You cannot realistically sandbox it.**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
import mymodule

var = getattr(mymodule, variablename)
```

Answer (score 10):

`getattr(themodule, "attribute_name", None)`

The third argument is the default value if the attribute does not exist.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a variable from the current module you're running in (and not another one):

```
import sys

# sys.modules[__name__] is the instance of the current module
var = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'var_name')
```

`var` can be of course a regualr variable, class or you anything else basically :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option, is to use INSPECT, and the getmembers(modulename) function.

It will return a complete list of what is in the module, which then can be cached.  eg.

```
>>>cache = dict(inspect.getmembers(module))
>>>cache["__name__"]   
Pyfile1 test

>>>cache["__email__"]
'name@email.com'

>>>cache["test"]("abcdef")
test,  abcdef
```

The advantage here is that you are only performing the look up once, and it assumes that the module is not changing during the program execution.

Comment: There is a tradeoff here between the overhead to generate the cache and the number of lookups performed. For example, when testing on the opencv "cv2" module it took roughly 30k lookups before inspect became faster than getattr